Consistency strength of HoTT
What is the consistency strength of Homotopy type theory (HoTT) relative to various set theories (e.g., are there any known set theories that it can interpret)?  Does this question even make sense?

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588578/model-of-homotopy-type-theory-in-zfc. HoTT interprets ZFC; see HoTT book 10.5.11.

Thank you @NaïmFavier.  If HoTT can be interpreted in T = ZFC+countably many inaccessibles, that doesn't mean that it can't be interpreted in some theory with sets and classes that is equiconsistent with ZFC.  Is there a proof that HoTT is equiiconsistent with T?

"Homotopy type theory" is not a specific well-defined formal system, but the name of an entire subject, like "ring theory".  The specific formal system used in the HoTT Book is sometimes known as "Book HoTT", but even that is not fully precisely specified since the book doesn't give any general characterization of the class of higher inductive types that are allowed.

However, chapter 10 of the book constructs a model of (intuitionistic) ZF from a type-theoretic universe, which implies that it proves the consistency of ZF and is thus stronger than it.  By doing the same construction in higher universes, it should prove the consistency of ZF + n inaccessibles for any finite n.  Probably a fancier version of the interpretation, not lying inside any universe, shows that it is mutually interpretable with ZFC + countably many inaccessibles.

@MikeShulman Do you mean ZFC + 'There are countably many inaccessible cardinals' or do you mean ZFC + ${\text{‘There are at least}~n~\text{inaccessible cardinals’} : n \in \mathbb{N}}$? I don't see how you would be able to get the first one in a typical MLTT setup without having a universe above a countable sequence of universes (specifically because of issues with unbounded quantification).

François G. Dorais wrote a blog post about “ZFC + inaccessibles” a while ago, it might contain relevant information. And I think the discussion therein confirms that having universe $U_n$ indexed by external natural numbers amounts to having (at least) $n$ inaccessibles for every (external) $n$, and not internally having $\mathbb{N}$-many inaccessibles.

Is Book HoTT perhaps "re-interpretable" by some class theory like MK (Morse-Kelly) or ACT (Ackermann class theory) or ARC that is more expressive of classes and yet of lower consistency strength?  Some class theories are very expressive of classes and, for example, allow for having $P(V)$, $P(P(V))$, etc., where $V$ is the class of all sets, and $P(V)$ is the class of all subclasses of $V$, etc.  The blog post linked by @AndrejBauer is very informative.

Related post to my previous  question/comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425419/can-category-theory-be-founded-in-set-theory-using-worldly-cardinals-instead-of

I asked a similar question a few weeks back and got some interesting comments and an answer that may be relevant.

The proof theoretic strength of HoTT was studied by Rathjen in Proof Theory of Constructive Systems: Inductive Types and Univalence. The paper surveys a number of long known results on the relative strength of type theory and set theory, and then observes that the cubical set model of HoTT works in a sufficient constructive metatheory that the same observations apply. In particular, we can read off the following results:

Martin-Löf type theory with a countable hierarchy of univalent universes has the same proof theoretic strength as

$\mathbf{CZF}$ with for each $n$, an axiom asserting there is an increasing sequence of inaccessibles of length $n$.
$\mathbf{CZF}$ with inaccessibles as above but also the presentation axiom and other choice principles.
$\mathbf{CZF}$ with inaccessibles as above but also $\mathbf{LPO}$.
Kripke-Platek set theory with for each $n > 0$, an axiom asserting there are at least $n$ recursively inaccessible ordinals.


Removing W-types from type theory lowers the proof theoretic strength quite a bit. Martin-Löf type theory with a countable hierarchy of univalent universes but without W types has the same consistency strength as

$\mathbf{CZF}$ without $\in$-induction (but with infinity strengthened), inaccessibles as above, and $\mathbf{RDC}$.
Kripke-Platek without $\in$-induction, but with infinity strengthened, and every set is an element of an admissible set.
$\mathbf{ATR}_0$



I'll add to this that looking at the construction of HITs in Coquand, Huber, Mörtberg On Higher Inductive Types in Cubical Type Theory we can see that the construction of the standard examples of HITs (let's say pushouts, W-types and localization) only requires inductive types that are known to exist in $\mathbf{CZF}$ given enough inaccessibles, so exactly the same remarks apply to type theory with HITs as well as univalence. We can also see that the construction of finitary HITs only requires finitary inductive types in the metatheory, and so e.g. type theory with univalence, a natural number type and pushouts has the same strength as the weaker set theories above.
As people pointed out in the comments, there is an interpretation of $\mathbf{ZFC}$ in the HoTT book. This requires assuming the axiom of choice in type theory to work. However, the law of excluded middle is sufficient to get a model of $\mathbf{ZF}$, which has the same consistency strength as $\mathbf{ZFC}$ using Gödel's $L$. On the other hand the simplicial set model in Kapulkin, Lumsdaine, (after Voevodsky), The simplicial model of Univalent Foundations can be carried out in $\mathbf{ZFC}$ with sufficiently many inaccessibles. This gives type theory with excluded middle, univalence and HITs the same consistency strength as $\mathbf{ZFC}$ together with the same inaccessible set axioms as above for $\mathbf{CZF}$.
This just leaves the case of HoTT with propositional resizing. In the HIT cumulative hierarchy interpretation of set theory in HoTT, propositional resizing is only enough to get a model of $\mathbf{IZF}_R$, which is not known to have the same consistency strength as $\mathbf{ZF}$.
However, we can give an alternative construction, assuming the existence of a suitable HIT and combining the HIT cumulative hierarchy with double negation sheafification, as in Rijke, Shulman, Spitters, Modalities in homotopy type theory to get a model of $\mathbf{ZF}$, as follows. Note that we can interpret type theory into the reflective subuniverse for an accessible lex modality, as in Quirin, Lawvere-Tierney sheafification in homotopy type theory, to get an interpretation of type theory with univalence where the law of excluded middle holds. It remains to show that this interpretation contains a cumulative hierarchy HIT. Following Gylterud, From multisets to sets in homotopy type theory, the HIT cumulative hierarchy can be constructed as a retract of the Aczel cumulative hierarchy, which is just a W type, so we only need to show how to construct W types in the reflective subuniverse. We will use the free injective HIT denoted $\mathcal{J}_F$ by Rijke, Shulman and Spitters. It can be used to construct sheafification, as they showed, but note that W-types are also a special case of the free injective. For any W-type (including the Aczel hierarchy) we can combine the constructors for the W-type with the constructors for sheafification to get a HIT that does both simultaneously, to get a type which is an algebra for the polynomial associated to the W-type, a sheaf, and the initial such type, and so constructs the W-type in the reflective subuniverse as we needed.
I'll leave it open whether type theory with univalence and propositional resizing, but without assuming free injectives has the same consistency strength as $\mathbf{ZF}$.

Equiconsistency of $\mathbf{IZF}_R$ with $\mathbf{IZF}$ (and therefore $\mathbf{ZF}$) is still open as far as I know. What's weird though is that it was shown by Friedman and Ščedrov that $\mathbf{IZF}$ has strictly more provably total computable functions than $\mathbf{IZF}_R$.

Although I am curious, are you sure that the double negation sheafification is enough to actually get $\mathbf{ZF}$? I seem to recall that it's unknown whether this works over $\mathbf{IZF}_R$ and that in order to show that it works one needs either collection or the double complement axiom (i.e., that for any $x$, the class ${y : \neg\neg(y \in x)}$ is a set).

If it helps I think the double complement axiom has a more 'structural' characterization like this: The inverse image functor of a geometric morphism preserves well-foundedness. This gives a functor from ordinals (as a poset) to ordinals in the topos of $\neg\neg$-sheaves. Over $\mathbf{IZF}_R$, the double complement axiom should be equivalent to this functor having a right adjoint.
That said, it's not at all clear to me that this is provable in any of the standard constructive type theories.

(The statement about inverse image functors preserving well-foundedness seems to be folklore but it was also proven in this MSE question.)

The proof I had in mind works, although it requires a HIT that is technically just outside the ones that I listed as "standard". It's a little long, so I'll edit it into the answer.

It still isn't clear to me that the resulting thing will model full $\mathbf{ZF}$. The Aczel interpretation gives you replacement for statements of the form $(\forall x \in A)(\exists ! y)\varphi(x,y)$, but this needs to be witnessed constructively. For $\neg\neg$-sheaves you need something like weak replacement for statements of the form $(\forall x \in A)\neg\neg(\exists ! y)\varphi(x,y)$ (as in if that holds, then not not there exists a set $B$ such that $(\forall x \in A)\neg\neg(\exists ! y \in B)\varphi(x,y)$).

This is using the HIT cumulative hierarchy for the interpretation - the Aczel hierarchy is just being used to show that the HIT cumulative hierarchy exists. Also, the idea is to do a 2-step construction where the model of $\mathbf{ZF}$ is constructed in the internal logic of the reflective subuniverse, which satisfies LEM, so it's enough I think to interpret $\mathbf{ZF}$ given LEM and the HIT cumulative hierarchy, which is in the HoTT book.

Having said that, you can read off a more explicit description where the 2 steps are combined. In general existential quantifiers will need to be combined with double negation, but $(\exists ! y)\varphi(x, y)$ is equivalent to $\mathsf{IsContr}(\Sigma_{y : V_{\neg\neg}} \varphi(x, y))$ which only uses type constructors preserved by the inclusion from sheaves to the original universe.

Small correction: in the list of equivalent theories "with an axiom asserting" should be "with axioms asserting". In other words, Rathjen means "$T$ + there's at least 1 inaccessible + there's at least 2 inaccessibles + ..."

I'll think how to phrase it a bit better - I did intend it to mean "for each n, an axiom stating...".

HoTT+Propositional Resizing should fall roughly in the same bucket as Power-CZF, Power-KP, CZF+negative powerset, and (I)Z+<Bachmann–Howard many levels of the cumulative hierarchy, as in Thm. 15.1 of Rathjen's Constructive Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory, Power Set, and the Calculus of Constructions.

@UlrikBuchholtz I thought that at first, but I think that adding enough universes/inaccessibles and propositional resizing messes it up: The only axiom of IZF missing from Power-CZF is full separation. If you have a set X sitting inside an inaccessible set V, then an instance of full separation in V becomes an instance of bounded separation in the next universe level up, say $V'$, and so we get $Y \subseteq X$ with $Y \in V'$. Then in order to get propositional resizing we want P({1}) to be the same in V and V', which combined with function regularity lets us show Y must already belong to V.

@aws I contest the correctness of Proposition 8.5 of From multisets to sets in HoTT (which is used to construct V from W-types) -- the author states (without proof) that $V$ is a quotient of the W-type $M$ by an equivalence relation $\approx$, but to show the induced map $M/\approx \to V$ is surjective requires some choice principles. (Indeed Section 9 of Semantics of higher inductive types gives an example of a HIT which doesn't exist in Gitik's model of ZF without uncountable regular cardinals, and all W-types do exist there.)

@Jem I guess it's not really spelt out in that paper (IIRC Håkon has explained it better other places but I don't know a reference offhand). $V$ really is a retract of $M$ - its the subtype of "hereditary embeddings" and you can construct the map $M \to V$ by recursively taking the image factorisation. In particular you explicitly have a section of the map $M \to V$ (the inclusion) so there isn't any choice needed to show it is surjective.
